# Charges inside a cube (given field at the surfaces)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

I recently solved a question which asked me to find the charge inside a cube of length $a$ placed in an electric field $\vec{E} = C x \hat{i}$.

Using Gauss law, I found the answer to be $C \epsilon_0 a^3$, irrespective of where the cube is placed.

I wonder how such a uniform charge density will create such an inhomogeneous and direction dependent electric field, $\vec{E} = C x \hat{i}$.

Comment: Hint: Are you familiar with the differential form of Gauss law? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Differential_form

Comment: No, I am not. Sorry. Just wondering how charges can be placed so that there's NO electric field (and flux) through the top and bottom surfaces of the cube. Or is my thinking flawed in a fundamental way?

Comment: The easiest way to get the described field would be to have a uniform slab of density charge between $x = a$ and $x = 2a$, extending to infinity in the $y$- and $z$-directions.  Note that it's not just the charges inside the cube that contribute to the field inside the cube;  the charges outside the cube contribute as well.

Comment: Michael Seifert, wouldn't that mean the field is the same at points on the x-axis? But the question says the field depends on the x-coordinate.

Comment: This particular configuration of electric field is unphysical, because it gives you a constant charge density (you showed that the charge is proportional to the volume of the cube, irrespective of its size -- charge density is constant everywhere), and the field due to that configuration should not be along any particular direction. Instead, consider the electric field $C x e^{-b(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\hat{i}$, where $b$ is very small so that the exponential factor is almost 1 in the region of interest. Now, you can find the differential form of Gauss law to get the charge density $\rho(x, y, z)$.

Comment: For this particular example, Gauss law $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \rho/\epsilon_0$ implies $\rho(x, y, z) = C \epsilon_0 (1-2 b x^2) e^{-b(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$. Note that when $b$ is small, the charge density near the origin is almost constant, $C \epsilon_0$, which you obtained. But the charge density decreases in magnitude and also switches sign for large values of $x$

Comment: Thank you so much! That gives me something to think about.